# how to match a certain value inside an array using eloquent laravel 5.8?

Tags: php, laravel

In validation I didn't set the product field name to unique but want to it unique in some ways like products with same user_id, I want a single user have unique products name. So did some code to match value which is product field name to an array of product names from database.

```
    $products = Product::find(auth()->user()->id)->get();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
        $pro_name = $product->name;
    }

    $value = Input::get('name');

    if ($value == anyOf($pro_name) {
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume user_id is not the primary key to your product table. so you can't use find. do it like:

```
$products = Product::where(user_id, auth()->user()->id)->get();
```

you need an array of products name. get it like this:

```
$pro_name = Product::where(user_id, auth()->user()->id)->pluck('name')->toArray();
```

to check the array for a certain key use:

```
if (in_array($value, $pro_name)) {
    return false;
}
```

also you can do the whole thing like this:

```
$value = Input::get('name');

$product = Product::where(user_id, auth()->user()->id)->where('name', $value)->first();

if ($product){
return false;
}
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to define this validation using standard Laravel validation:

```
    $this->validate(
        $request,
        [
            'name' => \Illuminate\Validation\Rule::unique('products', 'name')
                ->ignore($id) // id of product being updated. If it is a new product you can remove this, or pass null
                ->where(function ($query) {
                    return $query->where('user_id', \Auth::user()->id);
                })
        ]
    );
```

Comment: Thanks it helps but not really on what I've asked, helps on update record.